# How to merge 2 different auth information?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

First, I am registering with email and logout, then I do FB login which has same email. Currently its creating as two different users. I want those two accounts to be merged. I look into "link" logic in firebase documentation. But we can link the account with the existing loggedin account. Can anyone give me the solution to fix this issue?

I am using,

```
let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: accessToken.tokenString)
FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credential, completion: { (user, error) in 
})
```

But it's creating as a new user even if the FB email id is already registered.

Comment: This documentation page describes how account linking works on iOS: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking. It's a bit finicky (in my experience). So if you have problems making it work, share the [minimal code that shows where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You must have "multiple accounts per email" instead of "One account per email address" enabled in the Firebase Console (Authentication section ->  SIGN-IN METHOD, bottom of the page) for your project. That setting will allow multiple accounts with the same email which match your symptoms.

Comment: but it will create two different accounts.

Comment: You will need to switch to "one account per email" so you can always have one account for all providers that return the same email: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716 So when you sign in with a new provider that has the same email as an existing one, the Firebase Auth backend will return an error that the credential already exists. You will then need to link the new credential to the existing account.